# What causes the network to slowdown when a new protocol activates?

Tags: baking, protocol, endorsement

When Babylon activated there was a period of 30+ minutes where endorsements and bakes were very unstable and we ended up hitting some quite high priorities.  I'm curious to know why this is the case and what steps need to be taken to ensure priority 0 baker's get their slots on the early blocks, it seems simply being up to date is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Babylon changed just about every single KT1 in the blockchain by adding the manager.tz smart contract code. Babylon also made many other internal changes. Every single node, before the 1st block of the Babylon cycle, must recalculate everything. That takes CPU/Disk/Memory/Time.